# bootstrap server. Error in iPhone SDK

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, bootstrapping

Can anyone help for the following ERROR:

Couldn't register com.india.XXX with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.

here m using xcode 4.1 and i have same project folders in my local desk.

When ever i open multiple projects with the same name its showing the above error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the fixes that the links Saif contain may work for some, but not for me.

I have a very simple solution without restarting that will usually get you through the day.

When you get this error, before you do anything else, build for the other device (if you are running a universal application).

When you build for the other device, it kind of "overwrites" the process that creates this error.  Once the other device is up and running, immediately build for the device that created the error.  This will work most if not all the time, and will save you time digging through the multitude of fixes you will find in the other links.

I tried almost all of the fixes found there and none of them worked in my case.  This works, but you should check your appDelegate for any bugs in your willEnter/didEnter (and other related methods).